# How do I pass 2 arguments to a getter in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

So, not sure if this is the correct way of going about this but I am trying to create a getter which returns a gradient based off of 2 colors passed to it via a function. So far I have:

Function being called

```js
<v-card-text
        style="height: 120px"
        :style="{
            'background-image': backgroundImage(card.color1, card.color2),
        }"
        flat
    ></v-card-text>
```

computed:

```js
backgroundImage() {
            return this.backgroundImage(color1, color2)
        },
```

getter:

```js
getters: {
        backgroundImage: () => (color1, color2) =>{
            let bgImage =
                'linear-gradient(to top right, ' + color1 + ',' + color2 + ')';
            return bgImage;
        }

    }
```

But when I run it now, I get this error

```js
Error in render: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
```

Not sure what I did wrong or if this is the correct way to handle this sort of function in Vuex?

Answer (score 1):

Send the arguments as object:

```
bgImg() {
  return this.backgroundImage({color1: color1, color2: color2})
  return this.backgroundImage({color1, color2}) // or shortcut
}
```

Trigger your action (not in getters)

```
backgroundImage(payload) => {
  const {color1, color2} = payload
  return 'linear-gradient(to top right, ' + color1 + ',' + color2 + ')';
}
```

or shortcut

```
backgroundImage({color1, color2}) => {
  return `linear-gradient(to top right, ${color1}, ${color2})`;
}
```

Actually this is the proper setup:

```
export default {
  state: {
    backgroundImage: {},
  },

  mutations: {
    SET_BG_IMG(state, payload) {
      state.backgroundImage = payload;
    },
  },

  actions: {
    setBgImg({ commit }, payload) {
      const {color1, color2} = payload
      const myImg = `linear-gradient(to top right, ${color1}, ${color2})`;
      commit('SET_BG_IMG', myImg);
    },
  },

  getters: {
    backgroundImage: (state) => state.backgroundImage,
  },
};
```

In your view:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ backgroundImage }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'YourComp',
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['backgroundImage']),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setBgImg(lang);
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['setBgImg'])
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I still get the same error sadly: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 1):

The call stack error is caused by the recursion of this computed calling itself:

```js
backgroundImage() {
  return this.backgroundImage(color1, color2) // <-- calling itself recursively
}
```

Try this instead:

```js
backgroundImage() {
  return this.$store.getters.backgroundImage;
}
```

Now the computed calls the getter instead of itself.  Notice that it is returning the getter without executing it because you do that already when calling it in the template.

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/1ds06g2t/)